# tsql transaction level row wise locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

First of all sorry if my English is not good.

I'm facing a problem with respect to transaction isolation level. My current isolation level is read committed.But it leads table to dead lock some times.
For example

```
create table tmp(id int,name varchar(20))
insert into tmp(id,name)
values(1,'Binesh')
       ,(2,'Bijesh')
       ,(3,'Bibesh')
begin transaction
update tmp set name ='Harish' where id=2
```

And I'm trying to get in another query window

```
   select * from tmp where id=1
```

It is locking the table so it is not giving any records until I rollback or commits the first one

I tried

```
ALTER DATABASE db
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT On
ALTER DATABASE db
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION on
```

It not locks the table but it gives old value for id =2

```
select * from tmp where id=2
```

returns me Bijesh where I'm expecting a locking

I'm expecting a way like if id=1 it will work fine, but if id =2 it will wait until the other transaction overs.

Hopes your help.....

Thanks in advance

Binesh Nambiar C

Comment: SQL Server is **NOT** locking the table - it is locking those rows (with id values from 1 to 3) that you're freshly inserting. Those cannot be read - until the `INSERT` is committed.

Comment: use WITH NOLOCK it will resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your replays and thanks a lot for formating the question for me.I also thought as marc tells upto now(Last 10 yrs). But currently some projects started to go for dead lock which are in scheduled tasks. That lead for this experiment. Insert is not under any transaction in my example. If you have doubt try once in query window...

Comment: Hi mohan, witn(nolock) is not what i'm expecting. it works as isolation level read uncommitted.I'm expecting a row level locking. But i'm able to get either table locking or no locking.

Comment: You forgot to end the transaction by calling commit

Answer (score 0):

This is not a deadlock you're experiencing.

Your second query is blocked because it has to scan the entire table. During the scan, it encountered the row being updated (exclusively locked), so it waits until the lock is released (ie transaction ends).

If engine knew that the id column is unique (primary key or unique constraint), you will not get blocking here, because it wouldn't have to do scan on entire table but would rather stop on first match.

Keep ypur transactions short, provide alternative access paths to data (indexes) and try not use "select *".

Also, think carefully whether you really want to use the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.